# dynamically add and process entries for an inventory (forms)

Tags: php, arrays, forms, html, post

I have this inventory setup wherein I have a quantity, a drop down for selecting a product and it's corresponding price, and total cash amount for that respective product. This is the code for the user input.

```
<input type = 'number' name='prod_quantity' value='1'/>
<?=form_dropdown('prod_selected',$prod_opts)?>
<input type = 'text' name='prod_amount' disabled='disabled' onblur="updateAmount()"/>
<button>Add Entries</button>
```

However, this only limits to 1 entry after entering the data. And surely the user wants more entries to add. How can I repeatedly add an entry one by one without affecting the whole inventory after submitting it for processing?

NOTES:

(A 2 dimensional array with an N x 3 would be an idea -- e.g. $_POST['inventory'] as a 2-d array)

Comment: Do u mean dynamically adding text boxes?

Comment: yes it is, adding the same set of inputs.

Comment: then try to use javascript or jquery .check this link http://www.mkyong.com/jquery/how-to-add-remove-textbox-dynamically-with-jquery/